# Embed SDL2/SDL_GPU Inside Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, c++14, sdl-2

At the moment I am trying to draw a SDL2/SDL_GPU frame (for rendering drawing and images) inside a Qt window. I intend on making a view port for a 2d tile map editor using this. So far I have searched around and have not found a working solution. At the moment, my dirty solution is that I have a separate SDL window with a renderer drawn always on top and fixed to the Qt window position to fake this effect. Is it worth continuing to do this? or how can I embed SDL's Renderer or SDL_GPU (Either one) within a Qt window?

Q2:
Also, there is a error that occurs during compilation when using Qt and SDL. "WinMain aleady defined at qtmain.lib". Is my current fix for this(in the code below) good or is there something else that I can do to fix this in a better way?

Here is my current working solution...

Main.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#undef main         //Error happens with winmain if i dont have this

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setFixedSize(600, 480);
    w.show();


    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <qtimer.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
    SDL_Window * wnd;
    SDL_Renderer * r;

    Q_SLOT void update();
};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    wnd = SDL_CreateWindow("", (this->x() + this->width() / 2) - 150, (this->y() + this->height() / 2) - 150, 300, 300, SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS | SDL_WINDOW_ALWAYS_ON_TOP);
    r = SDL_CreateRenderer(wnd, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(r, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(r, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(r);

    auto timer = new QTimer(parent);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(0);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(r);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(wnd);
    SDL_Quit();
}

Q_SLOT void MainWindow::update()
{
    SDL_SetWindowPosition(wnd, (this->x() + this->width() / 2) - 150, (this->y() + this->height() / 2) - 150);
}
```